# calling method in c++

Tags: c++, methods, switch-statement

How to create a method of operation(int op) with a numeric parameter so I can call other methods by operation(1) or operation(3)? I guess that I need to create a switch but I'm not sure how.

```
int subtraction(int n1, int n2) { //e.g. of simple method
    return n1 - n2;
}

int multiplication (int n1, int n2){
    return n1*n2;
}

int operation(int op) {
    // code that will call the method subtraction when I press 1.
    // same for multiplication...
}

int main () {
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use an `if` statement?

Comment: Why not attend the lectures and learn this stuff?

Comment: I think he's asking how to use a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int operation(int op, int n1, int n2) {
    switch( op )
    {
        case 1:
            return subtraction(n1, n2);

        case 2:
            return multiplication(n1, n2);

        default:
            // default case, when the op value is neither 1 or 2
            cout << "Error! << endl;
            return 0;
    }
}
```

@Edit: Added default case as suggested below. Also, I think that you should make your variables name's more descriptive.

Comment: need a default just in case

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. But it gave me an error on line with return multiplication(int n1, int n2); //type name is not allowed. too few arguments in fucntion call

Comment: The default should return a value

Comment: I've fixed the two calls in this code. You clearly didn't want to try to return a function prototype..

Comment: Error 1 error C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ')' Error 2 error C2660: 'Numbers::subtraction' : function does not take 0 arguments
same for the multiplacion, any ideas whats wrong? EDIT: thanks its working now.

Comment: Last question, how do I call it in main?